# Populate a dropdownlistfor with values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm a beginner in MVC and am trying to populate a `DropDownListFor` tag with values.

Here's what I found out right now which helped me a bit to construct my code:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1705047.aspx/1

So in my controller there are now 2 classes, the main class `(ObjController : Controller)` and another class I made up following the above example.

The other class looks like this:

```
public class ItemCostViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Item Cost :")]
    public string ItemCostCode { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ItemCostViewModel> GetItemCosts()
    {
        return new List<ItemCostViewModel>
        {
            new ItemCostViewModel() {Id = 1, ItemCostCode = "One"},
            new ItemCostViewModel() {Id = 2, ItemCostCode = "Two"},
            new ItemCostViewModel() {Id = 3, ItemCostCode = "Three"},
            new ItemCostViewModel() {Id = 4, ItemCostCode = "Four"},
            new ItemCostViewModel() {Id = 5, ItemCostCode = "Five"},
            new ItemCostViewModel() {Id = 6, ItemCostCode = "Six"}
        };
    }
}
```

So the goal here is to populate a `DropDownListFor` with values that shows "One" but from which I can refer to the id in the controller's code. My though is that if the user select "One", I get an integer value of 1 and I can treat it accordingly.

I've tried this line of code in the **.cshtlm** view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemCostCode , new SelectList(new Project1.Controllers.ItemCostViewModel().GetItemCosts(), "Id", "ItemCostCode"))
```

But sadly it provokes a crash since the `ItemCostCode` is not located in the controller:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061:'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project1.Models.ObjectInfo>' does not containt a definition for "ItemCostCode" (...)
```

I'm confused and I am not sure about what I am doing right now, and how. Could anybody help me out and explain what's wrong, and/or how to correct it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: First of all, in MVC you should be creating your lists in the controller and then passing them off to the View either as the model, or (in your case) through the ViewData (or ViewBag) dynamic variable. Second, you need to actually convert the items into an IEnumerable of SelectListItem or of DropDownItem.

Comment: That was what I was doing up to now. But when I encountered problems people kept telling me that I should not use DropDownList but rather DropDownListFor (and I have still yet to figure out how DropDownListFor works).

Comment: Also, I wanted to be able to show something (the string) and obtain a value (int).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I recommend doing to solve your problem:

1) Change the signature of that `GetItemCosts()` method to returning a List. You're doing it anyway, and it'll be easier in subsequent steps.

2) In your controller set the following (using whatever you do to call `GetItemCosts()`):

```
var itemCodeList = new List<DropDownItem>();

GetItemCosts().ForEach(ic => itemCodeList.Add(new DropDownItem { Value = ic.ID, Text = ic.ItemCostCode} );

ViewData["ItemCodes"] = itemCodeList;
```

3) The line in your View should now be able to look like the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemCostCode , ((IEnumerable<DropDownItem)(ViewData["ItemCodes"])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally, I must admit that all of you were right.

Here's what I have done which is WAY simpler than the code I was doing:

In my controller I created a dictionnary that I attributed to a `ViewBag` like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictObjCost = new Dictionary<string, int>
            {
                {"One", 1},
                {"Two", 2},
                {"Three", 3},
                {"Four", 4},
                {"Five", 5},
                {"Six", 6}
            };

            ViewBag.itemCostValue = new SelectList(dictObjCost, "Value", "Key");
```

And in the `.cshtml`:

```
Item Cost : @Html.DropDownList("itemCostValue ", String.Empty)
```

So now my value shows as "One", "Two" and so on.

When I get the view, I pass the '`int? itemCostValue`' parameter and everything works perfectly.

Thank you everyone to have made me realize what I was doing :)